# How to edit XML file shown in a ListView in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, forms

I am working on a C# application for a scanning device and I came across a problem. I get my configuration settings from an xml file, that I get from a server every time the application is run. However, if the configuration is wrong, I can't request a new configuration because the Server Url is in the xml. So I decided I want to have editing functionality. Here's how I show the config:

```
    private void list()
    {
        if (this.listViewConf.Items.Count != 0)
            this.listViewConf.Items.Clear();

        this.addItem("Operator", Data.cuser);
        this.addItem("Warehouse", Data.cware);
        this.addItem("Server URI", Config.uri(Config.socket));
        this.addItem("Timeout", Config.get(Config.socket, Config.atime));
        this.addItem("Config file", Config.path("config.xml"));
        this.addItem("Data backup", Config.path("data.xml"));

        this.listViewConf.Visible = true;
    }
    private void addItem(String name, String value) {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Text = name;
        item.SubItems.Add(value);
        this.listViewConf.Items.Add(item);       
    }
```

Where listViewConf is a ListView. My questins are - how to know which row of the ListView is selected (given that I have a button Edit) and more importantly, how to edit the xml file? The ListView consists of Name | Value pairs and here's a sample config.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<wms>
    <setup>
        <config path="/Flash File Store/WMS/" file="config.xml" />
        <socket path="http://ware.aip/interface/ck/" file="socket.php" timeout="10000" />
    </setup>
    <users>
        <user id="1" code="01" name="User" ware="1" />
    </users>
    <warehouses>
        <ware id="1" code="T" name="Test" />
    </warehouses>
    <tasktypes>
        <type id="1" code="T" name="Test" />   
    </tasktypes>
</wms>
```

And also - I know its possible to create an editable ListView, but if there is a simpler solution (like with an edit button), I'd be happy to use it.
Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a serializable class from the XML using `xsd.exe`. Use this class to deserialize the data in the XMl into a graph of `POCO` objects, which in turn you can bind to the `ListView`. You can directly edit the objects now, rather than trying to estimate where in the XML nodes you should edit.

Once all editing is done, serialize the objects back into XML.